# Dozer Mapping issue with collections

Tags: hibernate, mapping, dozer

I have an issue with Dozer Mapping. The problem is that I whould to map a collection from my entity to my DTO.

The collection in the entity :

```
private List<Devis> devises = new ArrayList<Devis>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "idDemande")
public List<Devis> getDevises() {
    return this.devises;
}

public void setDevises(List<Devis> devises) {
    this.devises = devises;
}
```

In the DTO :

```
private List<DevisDto> devises = new ArrayList<DevisDto>();

public List<DevisDto> getDevises() {
    return devises;
}

public void setDevises(List<DevisDto> devises) {
    this.devises = devises;
}
```

The error :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection
MapId: null
Type: null
Source parent class: com.bnpparibas.realestate.workflowtma.entity.Devis
Source field name: lignes
Source field type: class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
Source field value: Unable to determine source field value
Dest parent class: com.bnpparibas.realestate.workflowtma.dto.DevisDto
Dest field name: lignes
Dest field type: java.util.List
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing the mapping after the Hibernate session is closed. Keep it open, or set `FetchType` to `EAGER`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using FetchType to EAGER then you have to create a new service which call a new Dao class in here you use Criteria or any other language for query once you get list of Devis then mapped into Dto class but using mapCollection() which is designed by you in this method you can map entity to dto and return dto list. You are not getting result because you map List to Class this is why you geting error. If you don't get then leave comment for me I will explain through code . If you give some code here.